# How can I install Python's pip3 on my Mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to install pip3, but I'm not having any luck. Also, I tried `sudo install` and it did not work. How could I install pip3 on my Mac?

```
sudo easy_install pip3
Password:
Searching for pip3
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip3/
Couldn't find index page for 'pip3' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
   
No local packages or download links found for pip3
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip3')
```

Comment: To install or upgrade pip, download `get-pip.py` from the [official site](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html)

Then run the following command: `sudo python get-pip.py` and it will install the pip for your python version which runs the script.

Comment: So, is it mac or ubuntu? In any case, I'd recommend not to mess with the system Python if you don't have to, and look into [`pyenv`](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) (it installs `pip` by default, too)

Comment: I am assuming you have Python 2.X as if you had python3, you will also have pip3. If you have Python 2, then it makes more sense for you to install pip ( not pip3 ) so just try 'easy_install pip'

Answer (score 375):

### UPDATED - Homebrew version after 1.5

According to [the official Homebrew page](https://brew.sh/2018/01/19/homebrew-1.5.0/):

> On 1st March 2018 the python formula will be upgraded to Python 3.x and a python@2 formula will be added for installing Python 2.7 (although this will be keg-only so neither python nor python2 will be added to the PATH by default without a manual brew link --force). We will maintain python2, python3 and python@3 aliases.

So to install Python 3, run the following command:

```
brew install python3
```

Then, the `pip` or `pip3` is installed automatically, and you can install any package by `pip install <package>`.

---

### The older version of Homebrew

#### Not only `brew install python3` but also `brew postinstall python3`

So you must run:

```
brew install python3
brew postinstall python3
```

Note that you should check the console, as it might get you errors and in that case, the `pip3` is *not* installed.

Comment: "brew install python" failed for me as it needed sudo. Then it wouldn't rerun as homebrew thought the install was success. Running "brew link python" "brew postinstall python" seems to have worked and now I have pip3 :-)

Comment: I have 1.7.6 but I can't install pip3. I can install python3.

Comment: I had to do a brew reinstall python to get tit to work.

Comment: This did not work for me. pip3 was not installed with python3 automatically. I removed it all  - `brew uninstall python3`, went to official python and did it there. Worked.

Comment: @MoteZart Did you run the post install command? It is necessary if you use the older version of home brew.

Comment: I'm running Homebrew 2.1.7 and had to run the `brew postinstall python3` command to get pip3.

Answer (score 97):

You could use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh).

Then just run:

```
brew install python3
```

Comment: does it also install pip3?

Comment: Yes it does install pip3

Comment: For some reason it didn't work. anw, put in .profile: `pip3='python3 -m pip'`

Comment: This doesn't work, added it to my .profile but still getting pip3: command not found

Comment: Sometimes this breaks silently and pip3 is not installed -- and you need to run "brew postinstall python3" like in @Blaszard 's answer (if there are errors, fix it, in my case it was sequence "sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python3.6/; brew unlink python3; brew link python3; brew postinstall python3" )

Answer (score 75):

I solved the same problem with these commands:

```
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python3 get-pip.py
```

Comment: get-pip.py will downloaded to current directory, in case u wonder.

Comment: Did it in separate screen before brew could figure out its update package : )

Answer (score 26):

For me `brew postinstall python3` didn't work. I found this solution on the GitHub [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) issues page:

```
$ brew rm python
$ rm -rf /usr/local/opt/python
$ brew cleanup
$ brew install python3
```

Comment: Seems like the hard remove with `rm -rf /usr/local/opt/python` and the reinstallation and a manual `brew postinstall python` worked for me =)

Comment: @HugoCantacuzene yes, you're right. Corrected the answer.

Comment: not anymore as of mid 2018? It seems `brew install python` now installs python 3

Comment: Worked for Mac OS Mojave for me 9/19/19. Finally. Thank you.

Comment: This worked for me on Mac OS Catalina.  However you can just do `brew install python` as it resolves to installing Python 3.  Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

Python 3 was working successfully, but without pip3. I tried advice from Stack Overflow, Quora and others (numerous installs and uninstalls).

Python 3 was always fine, but without pip3. Finally I downloaded Python3 from:
https://www.python.org/downloads/

By simple mouse clicks and everything (Python 3 + pip3), it is working fine now.

Comment: I was having a lot of problems trying to make pip3 work (installing with Homebrew) in my MacBook M1 and a fresh install from the web fixed it for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried many options and failed. This simple solution works like a charm for me. I got pip immediately.

Answer (score 10):

Similar to Oksana but add python3

```
$ brew rm python 
$ brew rm python3 
$ rm -rf /usr/local/opt/python
$ rm -rf /usr/local/opt/python3
$ brew prune 
$ brew install python3
$ brew postinstall python3
```

Seem now work for pip3 under mac os x 10.13.3 Xcode 9.2

Comment: You should now call brew cleanup instead of brew prune

Answer (score 9):

To install or upgrade pip, download **get-pip.py** from the [official site](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/). Then run the following command:

```
sudo python get-pip.py
```

and it will install `pip` for your python version which runs the script.

Comment: Where does pip get installed?  it is still not found in my path nor the current directory with get-pip.py

Answer (score 7):

I ran the below where `<user>:<group>` matched the other `<user>:<group>` for other files in the `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/` directory:

```
sudo chown -R <user>:<group> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip*
brew postinstall python3
```

Answer (score 6):

I also encountered the same problem but `brew install python3` does not work properly to install `pip3`.

brre will throw the warning `The post-install step did not complete successfully`.

It has to do with homebrew does not have permission to `/usr/local`

**Create the directory if not exist**

```
sudo mkdir lib 
sudo mkdir Frameworks
```

**Give the permissions inside `/usr/local` to homebrew so it can access them:**

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

**Now ostinstall python3**

```
brew postinstall python3
```

**This will give you a successful installation**

Comment: `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*` does not work for me. This looks like bash scripting? What is `$(brew --prefix)/*`? Can you show an example of how to use proper syntax in terminal?

Answer (score 4):

After upgrading to [macOS v10.15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina) (Catalina), and upgrading all my vEnv modules, pip3 stopped working (gave error: "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable").

I found [question 58386953](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58386953/117259) which led to here and solution.

1. Exit from the vEnv (I started a fresh shell)
2. `sudo python3 -m pip uninstall pip` (this is necessary, but it did not fix problem, because it removed the base Python pip, but it didn't touch my vEnv pip)
3. `sudo easy_install pip` (reinstalling pip in base Python, not in vEnv)
4. cd to your `vEnv/bin` and type "source activate" to get into vEnv
5. `rm pip pip3 pip3.6` (it seems to be the only way to get rid of the bogus pip's in vEnv)
6. Now pip is gone from vEnv, and we can use the one in the base Python (I wasn't able to successfully install pip into vEnv after deleting)

Answer (score 0):

Installing Pip3

- Follow this [link](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) to download pip3 on your computer
- Follow the instructions on the page and then after successfully downloading Pip3, run python3 get-pip.py in your terminal
- This will install pip3 into your laptop and then you can check the installation of pip3 by running which pip3 in your terminal.

Now simply do `pip3 install <package>`

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Python 3, just execute `python3 get-pip.py` . It is just a simple command.

Comment: Unless you've upgraded to new MacOS, and are running virtual environment. That's non-trivial.