# Cannot import pandas after pip install pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I run the following command to install `pandas` via `pip`:

```
sudo pip install pandas --upgrade
```

which outputs

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pandas in /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy>=1.7.0 in /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already up-to-date: python-dateutil>=2 in /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already up-to-date: pytz>=2011k in /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.5 in /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2->pandas)
```

However, when I use `python3` in the command line, I cannot import `pandas`:

```
$ python3
>>> import pandas
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pandas'
```

It appears that this is in the correct location, as

```
which python3
```

is in the following location:

```
/opt/local/bin/python3
```

Executing within python3

```
 >>> import sys
 >>> print(sys.version)
```

outputs

```
'3.4.5 (default, Jun 27 2016, 04:57:21) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)]'
```

Why can't I import pandas?

EDIT: I'm using pip version pip3:

```
pip --version
```

outputs

```
pip 8.1.2 from /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)
```

Comment: what does `which pip` tell you?

Comment: @jxramos `/opt/local/bin/pip`

Comment: Hmm, looks same place as python3. I had issues around this sort of thing while having multiple Python versions installed and pip was installing to a version I didn't intend. Do you have python2 anyplace? Check its installed modules and maybe run a test of adding some entirely new module and see where it winds up.

Comment: What is the output of `import sys; print(sys.path)`?

Comment: @JohnGordon The output is:
['', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pydot_ng-1.0.1.dev0-py3.4.egg', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mhcflurry-0.0.6-py3.4.egg', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyVCF-0.6.7-py3.4-macosx-10.11-x86_64.egg', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/distribute-0.7.3-py3.4.egg',

Comment: @JohnGordon '/Users/shanzhengyang/src/bayesrl', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tables-3.2.4.dev0-py3.4-macosx-10.11-x86_64.egg', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python34.zip', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4',

Comment: @JohnGordon '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/Users/shanzhengyang/Library/Python/3.4/lib/python/site-packages', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages']

Comment: I'm stuck. No idea why this doesn't work.

Comment: google pip3 to install python 3 packages. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573159/how-do-install-pip3-on-my-mac

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your OS uses pip2 by default. This could be checked by typing:

```
$ pip --version
pip 8.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

Try to use `pip3` command like that:

```
sudo pip3 install pandas --upgrade
```

Comment: for `pip --version`, I get `pip 8.1.2 from /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)`

This isn't the problem, I'm afraid.

Comment: @ShanZhengYang try to do `sys.path.insert(0, '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages')` and then `import pandas`. Or start python3 with PYTHONPATH like that: `PYTHONPATH=/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH python3`