# installing packages for python 3

Tags: python, macos, module, package, pip

I tend to run my code in Jupyter notebooks, and these run in python 3. I also have python 2 on my computer. I installed `pip3` so I'd be able to install packages specifically for python 3 but this doesn't seem to be working out for me:

```
mba$ pip3 install multidict
Collecting multidict
  Using cached multidict-2.1.2.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: multidict
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for multidict ... done
  Stored in directory: /Users/mba/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/6e/f3/6a/c1ff64511c3dc2964ade4f9e59f4d7dfc050bd77e0fcc78ca5
Successfully built multidict
Installing collected packages: multidict
Successfully installed multidict-2.1.2
mba:~ $ python3
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:52:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import multidict
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'multidict'
>>> import sys.
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import sys.
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:52:12) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)]'
>>>
```

Notice that the `multidict` install with `pip3` succeeded, but when I ran `python3` and tried to `import multidict`, this failed. How can I install the proper Python 3 version of the package I want?

For reference, I'm on Mac OS X El Capitan. I've read the existing SO posts and tried following the advice in these:

- [How to install pip for Python 3 on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082935/how-to-install-pip-for-python3-on-mac-os-x)
- [How do install pip3 on my mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573159/how-do-install-pip3-on-my-mac)

These have not done the trick. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: check `pip3 -V` and try `pip3.5 -V`. Maybe you have few Python3 version and `pip3` use different version than `3.5.2`

Comment: or use `python3 -m pip install multidict`

Comment: btw, `anaconda` should have own program to install packages - `conda`

Comment: @furas thank you, your first suggestion worked! (I had already tried using anaconda, it doesn't seem to have multidict)

Comment: @furas Perhaps you should post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I put comment as answer (after 4 years) because @user20272 suggested that it is useful.

---

Maybe you have few `Python` installed and `pip3` uses different version than you expect.

First you can check versions (upper `V`)

```
pip3 -V 

python3 -V
```

You may also check if you don't have also similar commands

```
pip3.5 -V
pip3.6 -V
pip3.7 -V

python3.5 -V 
python3.6 -V 
python3.7 -V
```

Sometimes the simplest method is to use `python` to install it

```
python3 -m pip install multidict
```

---

Later you can try to clean this mess and put correct `pip3.x` in place of `pip3`.

On Linux (and probably on MacOS too) you can go to folder with `pip3` and `pip3.x`, remove `pip3` and create symbolic link using

```
ln -s pip3.5 pip3
```

instead of copying file.

---

On Linux (and probably on MacOS too) you can find folder with `pip` using

```
which pip3
```

eventually

```
whereis pip3
```

Comment: The  `pip` (`pip3`, etc.) scripts are unreliable. Forget about them. Always use `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip` instead (or if you feel confident enough shorten it down to `python -m pip`, but almost never `pip`). -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/