# How to install troposphere for python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, troposphere

I'm running `macOS` version `11.0.1`.
I'm trying to import a module called `troposphere`
I have `Python2.7` as well as `Python3.9.1` installed
When I try to import troposphere using `Python2.7` like

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from troposphere import Template
```

It does work. But when I try to import the same using `Python3.9.1` like

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from troposphere import Template
```

It throws error like this

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'troposphere'
```

What should I do? Please help

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Probably duplicate of [macos - installing packages for python 3 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40314148/installing-packages-for-python-3)

Comment: I tried installing both via pip3 as well as pip. The problem persists idk why

Comment: Tried uninstalling it and ran command as mentioned in that comment. But says `Requirement already satisfied: troposphere in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.8.2)`

Comment: Then, are you sure `/usr/bin/python3` is Python 3.9.1?

Answer (score 0):

it is because the python interpreter you use to run your code doesn't have troposphere installed.

Managing multiple Python version on the same computer is tricky, But I will try to explain it.

I assume that you are using `python your_script.py` to run your code, and `pip install troposphere` to install package right? But think of this, how does your system know exactly which python you are running and which python to install package? Here's how to check the full path of your python command and pip command.

1. type `python` command enter python console
2. then type this:

```html
import sys

print(sys.executable)
```

3. navigate up and down little bit, you will find a bin folder include `bin/python` which is your interpreter and `bin/pip` which is your pip command. And there's a `lib/site-packages` folder, this is where third party library been installed to.
4. if you see import error, use the above method to locate the python interpreter and check the site-packages folder, most likely there's no such `troposphere` folder in it. Then you need to use the full path of the `<path-to>/bin/pip` to install troposphere. Then your problem is solved.

If you are using home brew or the python installer download from [www.python.org](http://www.python.org), your system probablly already messed up. The recommended way to manage multiple Python version is to use pyenv https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv. It allows you to install any python version and easy to delete them.

Answer (score -1):

Chek if the module was depreciated

Comment: In the future, until you have enough reputation, please try not to add incomplete answers and instead put things like this as comments.