# AioHttp Installation: multidict module error

Tags: python, pip, aiohttp

I tried installing the `AioHttp` package, as seen in the extract below. The installation failed with the `multidict` module.

```
root@ava:/home/cliquant/server/ava# pip3 install aiohttp
Collecting aiohttp
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/4f/62d9859b7d4e6dc32feda67815c5f5ab4421e6909e48cbc970b6a40d60b7/aiohttp-3.8.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    *********************
    * Accelerated build *
    *********************
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-0b29nbfp/aiohttp/setup.py", line 54, in <module>
        setup(**setup_kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 121, in setup
        dist.parse_config_files()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 494, in parse_config_files
        ignore_option_errors=ignore_option_errors)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 106, in parse_configuration
        meta.parse()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 382, in parse
        section_parser_method(section_options)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 355, in parse_section
        self[name] = value
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 173, in __setitem__
        value = parser(value)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 430, in _parse_version
        version = self._parse_attr(value)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 305, in _parse_attr
        module = import_module(module_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/tmp/pip-build-0b29nbfp/aiohttp/aiohttp/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
        from . import hdrs as hdrs
      File "/tmp/pip-build-0b29nbfp/aiohttp/aiohttp/hdrs.py", line 8, in <module>
        from multidict import istr
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'multidict'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-0b29nbfp/aiohttp/`
```

I got error when installing `aiohttp` with `pip3`.
**How can I fix this**?

NB: I can't find in google about it...

Comment: run `pip3 install multidict` first.

Comment: SOLVED thanks it asked me to install alot modules but i did and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Google came to your aid narrowing down on the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'multidict'`

To resolve, install the multidict module.
`python3 -m pip install multidict` or
`pip3 install multidict`

See this [GitHub issue #277](https://github.com/aio-libs/multidict/issues/277), and
this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40314148/installing-packages-for-python-3)

[Edit] For completeness, ensure you are installing in the correct environment `env`.
Also, check the version(s) of python installed on the system.

Comment: why isn't this automatic when installing aiohttp though?