# can't install pip for python3 macos mojave

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip, macos-mojave

I've been trying to install pip for Python3 on mojave. I've seen different posts on SO and other websites but nothing works.

for instance, in [How to install pip for Python 3 on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082935/how-to-install-pip-for-python-3-on-mac-os-x)

I follow the steps:

`curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py`

`python3 ez_setup.py`

`curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`

`python3 get-pip.py`

but when running `python3 get-pip.py` it reinstalls pip for python2.

Is there a way to install pip for python3 without removing python2 from the system?

Comment: Are you sure that the `pip` command isn't just linked to `pip2`? Does `python3 -m pip` run pip3?

Comment: thanks! this actually worked!

Answer (score 1):

This post suggests to use homebrew in order to install pip3: [How to install pip3 on my Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573159/how-to-install-pip3-on-my-mac)

Comment: thanks for the help, I had `brew` installed all along, but it actually worked with `python3 -m pip`