# pip3 "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" after update

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I am new in Python, I wanna install Jupyter Notebook in my console I enter the following:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

after that I have a error to use pip3 install other library, the console print:

```
File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I don't know what I have to do.

I use `sudo autoremove python3-pip` after that I use `sudo apt install python3-pip`

Comment: maybe it imports some of your file instead expected module and it has problem to run it - it can be ie. `main.py`. Did you try to use `pip` in different folder ?

Comment: I also had the same error.

Comment: Thanks for getting me started - I listed my procedure for fixing this on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573159/how-to-install-pip3-on-my-mac/59245705#59245705

Answer (score 66, accepted):

From the [link](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7205#issuecomment-541926212) by Bram, I just ran `python3 -m pip uninstall pip`, and it started to work again.

Comment: Can somebody explain this?

Comment: @SaifUrRahman: From the provided link it seems that this is a conflict between a user specific pip installation (which gets installed/upgraded by the OPs command) and the global pip installation provided by the operating system.

Comment: for some reason, I get a giant error starting with 'Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError:" when I run `pip install pandas` for example. what could that be about? using the command @Hyrial suggested did help me install pandas with pip3, when before i got the same "module not callable" error.

Answer (score 6):

The solution which worked for my situation is simply editing the pip3.8 file in the ubuntu environment.

Method1:

```
#!/path/to/.venv/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pip._internal.main import main  # <--- look at this import statement! 

if __name__ == '__main__':
     sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
     sys.exit(main())
```

method2:

The main function has to be imported or we can simply replace line

```
sys.exit(main())
```

As

```
sys.exit(main.main())
```

Comment: Thanks! method #2 worked for me. I'm nervous about it, because I'm afraid it will fail the next time I update /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/pip3.

Answer (score 6):

Use this

> python -m pip install --upgrade --user [name_of_your_package]

Answer (score 4):

As seen [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7205#issuecomment-541926212), you should be able to solve this by running the module from Python directly, i.e.

```sh
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 1):

In Windows edit C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py and replace

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from pip._internal import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

> Replace the last line with sys.exit(main.main()).