# Python pip module not working after upgradation

Tags: python, pip, librosa

I installed librosa using pip

> pip install librosa

After the installation, I got a message that I can upgrade my pip version and so I did.
Now, even when i type pip, I'm getting this error

> sys.exit(main())
>   TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

I checked the pip-script.py but did not understand anything

Comment: can you share the full sequence of commands you ran or at least the commands which result in error?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58386953/i-have-a-issue-with-pip3

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

yes the answer is as ArunJose_Intel mentioned.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

The issue was originally reported [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7205).

The explanation, as pfmoore explains on the original issue is:

> The --user upgrade won't have updated /usr/local/bin/pip, which will
>   still expect to see the old version of pip. But the user install takes
>   precedence, so what it sees is the new version.

So then the issue is the `local/bin/pip` expecting another version of pip.