# why is "pip3 --help" failing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I'm rebuilding a system after a crash: Ubuntu 16.04LTS.

```
$pip3 with any cmnd-line option fails as follows:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

FWIW, my end goal is to get iPython upgraded to using Python 3.6+, then to re-install Jupyter.

Suggestions?

Comment: Try to do `pip3 uninstall pip3` and then install pip again

Comment: same result. (same error message.)

Comment: iPython doesn't "use" or "upgrade to" a version of Python. You would install iPython **into** a particular version of Python... So what does `python3 -m pip --help` show?

Comment: The pip help page contents: (/usage, /commands, /general options).

Comment: Sounds like your `pip3` script may have fallen out of sync with your actual pip version.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58386953/i-have-a-issue-with-pip3) fixed it for me:

```
python3 -m pip uninstall pip
```

Comment: Confirmed after going down a couple of blind alleys. Thanks.