# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable facing this error while --upgrade pip setuptools

Tags: python, pip

I am getting the error while running `pip install --upgrade pip` setuptools command

error:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I have tried uninstalled python & pip and reinstalled again but still I am receving same error

Could any one help me on this

Comment: Are you able to use `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`? Seems a duplicate to this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58386953/510937 although I don't about about MacOS X and the issue there is for `pip3`...

Comment: The accepted answer there solved the issue for me (Win8.1 & Python 3.7) :-)