# Install opencv-python module

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I'm trying to install the opencv module without success, I think the problem is related to the version of python I'm using.
Indeed I upgraded to the 3.9.1 version but when I'm trying to install the module, I still receive a warning referred to the old version of python I had (i.e. 2.7).
How can I get rid of this situation and successfully install the opencv library?

[Error in bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5LKH.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the `pip` you are using in the insallation command conforms to `pip2` which is used for installing packages for `python2` (as is evident from the command output). You can verify the version by running:

```
pip --version
```

To solve the issue, use `pip3`:

```
sudo -H pip3 install opencv-python
```

If `pip3` is not installed, install it via HomeBrew:

```
brew install python3
```

It should install pip3 as well. Also, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573159/how-can-i-install-pythons-pip3-on-my-mac).