# pip command not found, virtualenv command not found on mac when installing django

Tags: python, django

Trying to learn python/django but cant even install django when i do `virtualenv .` or use the `pip` command, neither of them work on mac. python -V is 2.7.16, python3 -V is 3.8.2.

> pip command not found, virtualenv command not found on mac

Comment: please share how do you use virtualenv command

Comment: tried virtualenv -p python3 . and virtualenv . 
Returns command not found for both

Comment: Is there any way to install django without using pip as it doesnt work on my mac?

Comment: Just put it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573159/how-can-i-install-pythons-pip3-on-my-mac PS1 try `pip3` instead `pip`. PS2 virtualenv is not necessary for Django

Comment: is there anyway to just uninstall all versions of python and start again having so much bother with this

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't install virtual environment:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Comment: i get back
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==21.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2843, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()

Answer (score 0):

You can activate your venv, give a try to apt install of pip3 if not found and then use it to install django.

```
source ./venv/bin/activate

sudo apt install python3-pip

pip3 install django
```

If your venv is properly configured you should get that venv path like this (here venv = djongo):

```
djongo/pyvenv.cfg

djongo/bin:
activate       activate.ps1      chardetect       easy_install      ndg_httpclient  pip-3.7      python     sqlformat  wheel-3.7
activate.csh   activate_this.py  django-admin     easy_install3     pip             pip3.7       python3    wheel
activate.fish  activate.xsh      django-admin.py  easy_install-3.7  pip3            __pycache__  python3.7  wheel3

djongo/lib:
python3.7
```

Comment: what is that path? source /venv/bin/activate. Cant find that on my mac

Comment: This is the path to your virtual environment directory. If you use virtualenv properly you should get a folder with any name such as "venv" and ./venv/bin/activate in it (see my edit)

Comment: Well then you should read about what virtual environment means before going into...

Comment: I just want to learn django shouldnt be this much hassle

Comment: so don't use a virtual environment to make your stuff then...

Comment: well it seems to be the only way to install django using pip and virtual environment

Comment: then read about what virtual environment does mean and why you need to activate it using the process I described...