# Having trouble getting command line to work in Mac Terminal

Tags: python, terminal

I recently have had trouble getting my command line to work in Mac terminal. My knowledge isn't great so I assume this is a simple fix but as of a day ago, I can't get any commands to work in mac terminal (I think I may have updated recently which might have something to do with it). When I try to install a Python module by running the command "pip 3 install ..." I get the error "-bash: pip3: No such file or directory". Before this would work fine. I have been using bash without any issues but when I open up terminal I get this message: "The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`." but when I try to run that I get this error: "-bash: chsh: No such file or directory". Is the cause that I'm in the wrong directory? I've tried using the cd command and that works without an error but none of the other commands do. Additionally, I also get this message whne opening up terminal: "-bash: export: `/Users/nyname/Library/Python/3.7/bin:$PATH': not a valid identifier" Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: You probably need to install `python3` first in your Mac first to be able to use `pip3`. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47004414/7375347) for doing so using homebrew

Comment: @taxevader I have python3 installed or at least I did. I just don't understand why no commands are working?

Answer (score 0):

That last error is suspicious. Did you modify your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` manually? Can you show the contents of those? It looks like you've gotten the syntax for exporting a variable incorrect.

Comment: How do you I recommend I access it? I tried using the command "open -e. bash_profile" I get the error "-bash: open: No such file or directory".

Comment: Try opening it from some text editor, like whatever you'd normally use to write code.

Comment: Looks like I was able to get it, thanks!